# Correct way to call a singleton object in C++

Tags: c++, singleton

I've build a singleton class based on the hit [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern).

I've extended it with a `getMessage()` function, that will retrive an internal dictionary message - the dictionary needs to be loaded only once on the whole application, that is the reason of the singleton.

My code:

**Singleton.hpp**

```
class Singleton {

public:

    static Singleton& getInstance();
    std::string getMessage(std::string code);

private:

    Singleton() {}; 
    Singleton(Singleton const&) = delete;
    void operator=(Singleton const&) = delete;
};
```

**Singleton.cpp**

```
Singleton& Singleton::getInstance()
{
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}


std::string Singleton::getMessage(std::string code)
{
    /// Do something
    return "Code example.";
}
```

And the main code:

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
        Singleton* my_singleton;
        my_singleton = Singleton::getInstance(); **<-- ERROR HERE**

        cout << my_singleton->getMessage("a"); << endl

}
```

Main is giving me an error: `Cannot convert 'Singleton' to 'Singleton*' in assignment`

What is the correct way to "instantiate" the singleton and make use of the getMessage function.

Thanks a lot for helping...

Comment: you might want to look at this http://silviuardelean.ro/2012/06/05/few-singleton-approaches/

Comment: For Singleton* my_singleton2; if you print &my_singleton and &my_singleton2, it will be different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about you just call the function like this:

```
Singleton::getInstance().getMessage("a");
```

instead of assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Doesn´work and doesn´t make sense that I cannot store it in a variable...I need to fix howto store it in a variable, not to avoid it...

Comment: Actually this gave me a hint on how to solve it... Singleton& my_singleton = Singleton::getInstance(); then my_singleton.getMessage("a");

Comment: @Mendez no need the reference: just type it as: `Singleton::getInstance().getMessage("a");` if you want to short it use a macro: `#define theSingleton Singleton::getInstance()` and use it with the macro:  `theSingleton.getMessage("a");`

Answer (score 1):

You want to store a reference to your singleton, not a pointer.

```
Singleton& my_singleton = Singleton::getInstance();
```

Comment: Not worked. Compiler generated error 'singleton' declared as reference but not initialized and several others on Singleton code...

Comment: @Mendez You need to declare it and initialize in the same expression like in the code above

Comment: I'm using the exact same `Singleton` in my own code all the time, it should work. But i prefer to access it like @Christian (and with a `dot` instead of `->`)

Comment: @Mendez Please see that my answer does work in this online example: http://goo.gl/B9Ws4P